# How to hide UITextField text with subview?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uilabel

I need to hide text property of the UITextField with subview.
It seems quite straightforward, but unfortunately it doesn't work.
What do I do wrong?

Here's the code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let txtField = UITextField()
    txtField.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: 300, height: 30)
    txtField.text = "This text is hidden under UILabel"
    txtField.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    view.addSubview(txtField)

    let label = UILabel()
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 30)
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    label.text = "This text should appear on top"

    txtField.addSubview(label)
    txtField.bringSubviewToFront(label)
}
```

Comment: If you want to analyze what's happening, Xcode's "Debug View Hierarchy" feature is sometimes very useful.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?  This is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/244435).

Comment: Label is a validation message that appears when user taps on overlay view of the UITextField (if there is any). I try to show validation message, but if user already typed in anything, the message (UILabel) appears under that text.

Comment: I suggest you to make a toast (like android) for validation messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    let txtField = UITextField()
    txtField.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: 300, height: 30)
    txtField.text = "This text is hidden under UILabel"
    view.addSubview(txtField)

    let label = UILabel()
       let label = UILabel()
   // label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 30)
    label.frame = txtField.frame
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    label.text = "This text should appear on top"


    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    label.text = "This text should appear on top"

    view.addSubview(label) // add label on view with same position ...
```

OR you simply change the z order of lable than also it is working.

```
    let txtField = UITextField()
    txtField.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: 300, height: 30)
    txtField.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    txtField.text = "This text is hidden under UILabel"
    view.addSubview(txtField)

    let label = UILabel()
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: 300, height: 30)
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    label.text = "This Label should appear on top"
    label.layer.zPosition=1
    txtField.addSubview(label)
```

Comment: Your code works, but I need it to be subview of the UITextField.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's impossible to `addSubview` to `UITextField`. Instead use can add it to `view` over your text field.

Comment: Subview covers background of the UITextField but not the text.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        let sampleTextField = UITextField()
sampleTextField.frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 50, width: 300, height: 100)
sampleTextField.text = "This text is hidden under UIsampleBackgroundLabel"
sampleTextField.textColor =  UIColor.blackColor()
sampleTextField.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
view.addSubview(sampleTextField)

let sampleBackgroundLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 30))
sampleBackgroundLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
sampleBackgroundLabel.text = "This text should appear on top"


sampleTextField.addSubview(sampleBackgroundLabel)
sampleTextField.sendSubviewToBack(sampleBackgroundLabel)


}
```

Check using a loop.

```
if(condition == true)
        {
            sampleBackgroundLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        }
        else
        {
            sampleBackgroundLabel.textColor = UIColor.blueColor()

        }
```